# how to create a cursor responsive 3D sphere on website without direct coading?

Tags: web, animation, 3d, responsive

Can i know how to create a cursor responsive 3d sphere just with using any website builder tool or app? without using direct html/css/js. (a guy asked this in a interview)

let me know if there is any builder tools used to create things like this